# UserControl using WPF, MVVM and DP

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I am designing a `NumericUpDownControl` UserControl and have successfully implemented it in my `MainWindow.xaml` as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SettingsDialog.Controls.NumericUpDownControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SettingsDialog.Controls"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:SettingsDialog.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="20" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <RepeatButton Content="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="8" Height="10" FontFamily="Marlett" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <RepeatButton Content="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="8" Height="10" FontFamily="Marlett"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the code-behind of my UserControl, I have defined the following:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(int),
        typeof(NumericUpDownControl)
     );

  public int Value
  {
     get => (int)GetValue(ValueProperty);
     set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
  }
```

It works fine as I can use it in my MainWindow.xaml like this:

```
<controls:NumericUpDownControl Width="100" Value="10"/>
```

However, when I attempt to set a ViewModel for my UserControl, the TextBox within the UserControl no longer recognizes the `Value` dependency property. How can I properly implement a ViewModel for my UserControl while still allowing for the ability to set the `Value` property from outside the control? Is there an issue with my current implementation that is causing this issue?

Comment: In the constructor of the UserControl add DataContext =this;

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I want the UserControl to have a ViewModel as well.

Comment: Then set it to var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(); myViewModel.Value = this.Value; DataContext = myViewModel

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Thanks, that makes sense! I was curious if this is the best solution though! Since if pass it to ViewModel and change it later in ViewModel it will not reflect in the Dependency Property!

Comment: You cannot bind it to two different places, so I would say best solution will be the one @mm8 came with.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I know, I was just wondering what is the standard way to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: When your UserControl exposes dependency properties, it should under no circumstances explicitly set its own DataContext (neither to `this` nor to a "private" view model). Doing so breaks any DataContext-based bindings of its dependency properties. What people on the internet (and sadly also here) are telling you about a UserControl's DataContext and private view models is plain wrong. Just don't do that.

Comment: @Clemens That means all the inner logic of the control is done in code behind? Let's say I want to do some Validation for the entered Value here. Should I do that in the code-behind of the UserControl, right?

Comment: Yes. The code-behind is part of the control class itself. You might also consider creating a custom control instead of using a UserControl.

Comment: @Vahid Exactly. A control with bindable properties has its logic in its code behind, no private view model. There is not a single control in WPF that has a private view model.

Comment: @Clemens  and mm8 Thank you very much, Another aspect of WPF and MVVM was demystified for me today!

Comment: @Vahid Think about `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}"><local:MyUserControl Value="{Binding MyValue}"/></DataTemplate>` as the general use case. Whenever you pass an instance of MyViewModel to a ContentControl or a ContentPresenter (also in an ItemsControl), the DataTemplate instantiates a MyUserControl and passes the MyViewModel instance to its DataContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the `Value` property of the `UserControl` regardless of its `DataContext`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="20" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Am I going right about designing the UserControl or is there a better more standard way?

Comment: It depends. Generally speaking a UserControl should inherit the DataContext and you shouldn't explicitly set its DataContext property.

Comment: But, isn't a TextBox for example a Control itself? Are you suggesting that it does not have a ViewModel of its own in the code-behind although hidden from us?

Comment: A TextBox is a control and it certainly has no view model.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a UserControl to itself and to a ViewModel at the same time.

You would have to remove `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` from within the UserControl and make sure to pass the right `DataContext` to the UserControl when integrating it in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a sort of custom control another way to solve your problem is simply to use the propertychanged callback of your dependency property and every time it changes you simply update your Textbox's Text property:

```
    public partial class NumericUpDownControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int),typeof(NumericUpDownControl),new PropertyMetadata(OnValueChanged));

        private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((NumericUpDownControl) d).TextBox.Text = e.NewValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }

        public int Value
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        public NumericUpDownControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```